# Compare the cotangents.

Tags: trigonometry

Compare the cotangents of the smaller of the two acute angles in right triangles with sides: 3, 4, 5; 6, 8, 10; and 15, 20, 25. Do they increase by the amount that the sides are multiplied?

Q. What do they mean by, do they increase by the amount that the sides are multiplied, and how does one come up with $\frac{5}{4}$, for the cotangents to be equal with?

The three sets of cotangents are $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{5}{4}$, $\frac{3}{5}$; $\frac{6}{8}$, $\frac{10}{8}$, $\frac{6}{10}$; $\frac{15}{20}$, $\frac{25}{20}$, $\frac{15}{25}$. The cotangents in each case are equal to $\frac{5}{4}$. They don't change with the lengths of the sides, because the angles in similar triangles are equal.

I can tell that the first set easily multiplies to the other two sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $3$-$4$-$5$-triangle is similar to a $6$-$8$-$10$-triangle and a $15$-$20$-$25$-triangle because the ratio of lengths of any two corresponding sides are the same.

A cotangent of the smallest angle is simply a ratio of two sides of a triangle. Since the triangles are all similar, the ratios are all the same. Thus the cotangents of corresponding angles are all the same.

Another way to think about it is that the angles of similar triangles are identical. So the smallest angle of one of the triangles is the smallest angle for any of the triangles. So the cotangents of the smallest angles from any of the triangles will be the same as well.